# How to get all properties of a single instance

Tags: sparql

I would like to access all properties of a single instance with a SPARQL query (let's say https://dbpedia.org/page/Cristiano_Ronaldo). I could not figure out exactly how to write such a query despite my research. Some help would be appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the properties (without values), you can do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cristiano_Ronaldo> ?property ?z .
}
```

**Update:** Note that the IRI of the resource differs from the URL in your question, which leads to the web page representing the resource in question (thanks to @UninformedUser for pointing that out).

Comment: that will not work, the URI is always `/resource/` as `/page/` is just the URL which leads to the website representation of the RDF data

Comment: True, I just copy&pasted the URL from the question. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I think there is also a problem with accents in name. When I look https://dbpedia.org/resource/Kylian_Mbapp%C3%A9 , it just does not work.

Comment: Just use the unescaped version - <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kylian_Mbappé>